cannot process received configuration data zabbix proxy
I have installed and configured a Zabbix proxy version 6.4.13 and I am trying to add it to a zabbix server version 6.4.
The point is that, the zabbix servers catches the zabbix proxy and the last seen age, but it is unable to collect data from the devices where I have a zabbix agent or the SNMP enabled.
I have the zabbix proxy updated with the latest updates installed on it and two NIC one internall and another external.
There is a problem is that, my zabbix proxy does not ping succesfully the zabbix server. I have checked the zabbix_proxy logs: tail –f /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.log and I get the following error:
919:20240409:155837.401 received configuration data from server at "myzabbixserver.address.com", datalen 93902
919:20240409:155837.403 cannot process received configuration data from server at "myzabbixserver.address.com": unexpected field "httptest.status"
Note: The zabbix proxy is installed on an hyper-v machine and both are located inside of a DMZ zone. The rest of the devices that I am trying to monitor are located outside of this, but inside of the LAN. The operating system used on the zabbix proxy is: Ubuntu server 22.04.
What might be the problem?
